# User folder on 2nd partition with link?

Tags: mac, folders, user-account

I have a hackintosh system. Fully working one.

I have a secondary partition called "Storage". I would like to move my user folder from /Users/"Username" to "Storage"/"Username".

Afterward create a link from "Storage"/"Username" to /Users/"Username"

Is this possible? Anyone tried?

Don't wanna brake system before trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a symbolic link to do this. I used it on an old mac which required the OS to be within a certain distance from the beginning of the drive, so I had to partition my hard drive to ensure that it would be there. To create a symbolic link, you need to use the command `ln -s <source> <destination>` in Terminal.

However, it would be better to use the advanced options in the Accounts preference pane to move your home folder's location. You will need to unlock the preferences if required (using the lock icon in the bottom left corner), then right click on your account name and change the location of your home directory. Since you are putting it on a separate partition, the path will start with /Volumes/PartitionName. Copy the folder over to the other partition before changing this setting! Then log out and back in and it should be using the new home folder, and you will be able to delete the old one. You can still create the symbolic link just in case some applications improperly assume that your home folder is in the /Users folder.

Comment: @Jm2.me make sure you create a new user (with admin rights) BEFORE doing any of this. If you have problems with the old account, you might be unable to log in.

Comment: Very much agree with Mr. Marconcini, it is a good idea to have an admin user with a user folder on the boot partition if you normally have users on a second partition. I also have users on a separate partition and my setup seems to match ughoavgfh's.